# jquery ajax post dies after submit

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working on an ajax post that for some reason dies once it is posted. on my firebug the url shown becomes red.

the url being posted is `http://localhost:8080/dev/?mod=table&page=sale&col=1&order=DESC&view=`

the file **DOES** exist in the correct directory and my code does **alert('works'); on beforeSend** and **alert('works complete'); on complete** but nothing in being echoed back from server and like i mentioned earlier on firebug the url is red

```
   var url = "./?mod=table"+getAllURLParam(); //get all param's. (getAllURLParam() function used to pass $_GET's
   var poststr = "page="+page+"&col="+escape(column)+"&order="+direc+"&view="+view;

                $.ajax({type: "GET", 
                    url: url,
                    data: poststr,
                    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) { alert('works'); },
                    success: function(data)
                    {         
                        alert(data);
                       /*if (data == 'ERR:sql'){ alert('There was a sql error.'); }
                       else { $('#browseDIV').html(data); }*/
                    }, 
                    complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) { alert('works complete'); },
                    dataType: "html"});
```

my php code is just this..

```
<?php

echo '<h1>hello</h1>';

?>
```

i don't see what i'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to see if you get something when adding `error:function(jqXHR,status,text){alert(status+': '+text);}` to your ajax object. Since complete works but not success, there certainly an error. You will be able to find out what it is with this.

Comment: you could try the short hand functionality: `$.get(url).done(function(data) { alert(data) });`  just to see if it is giving the same error

Comment: Did you tried to do [asynchronous ajax request](http://www.phpmind.com/blog/2010/07/what-is-ajax-synchronous-and-asynchronous/). Just try to add `async: false` between the `beforeSend` and the `success`

Comment: @Salketer it just alerts `error: ` i'm using jquery 1.9.1

Comment: Tip: As far as possible, avoid using GET requests. They have data length limitations. Do a POST instead. Edit: give us the error code found in firebug.

Comment: You have to send headers from server

Comment: @Mysteryos — It's very hard to hit those length limitations when using GET for things GET was designed for. Don't abandon good use of HTTP verbs just because you can only have a couple of thousand characters in GET data.

Comment: @f.vincent ok adding `async: false` worked. mind explaining why tho? all my other ajax post worked fine without it

Comment: @quentin I did hit those limitations previously, and had to switch from GET to POST requests. You have, however, a good point.

Comment: @Mysteryos i've always thought that GET should be used if only trying to retrieve info and not making any changes to the DB

Comment: @user2636556 can you try my code

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say for sure without a screenshot of firebug, but usually the red text indicates that the resource was not found. Please check that you have an `index.php` file located in `http://localhost:8080/dev/` or rewrite the path to include the filename, such as this: `http://localhost:8080/dev/filename.php`.

Also, for debugging, you could alert (or console.log() - it's less invasive) something in the success part of the call, just to see if it's ever fired, which I doubt very much.

Comment: the directory does exist. one of the suggestions was to use `async: false,` and it worked. but reading more about it. `Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active` not sure why i have to set it to false. and why in the world it worked too

Comment: No, that seems strange. Please provide the errorcode from firebug - the red text indicates that something is wrong, but without the code, it's difficult to know what exactly.

Comment: errors is empty. even when i add `error:function(jqXHR,status,text){alert(status+': '+text);}` all i get is `error:`

Comment: Not that error: You mentioned that the URL was red in firebug? Please provide that error.

Comment: even when i do `http://localhost:8080/dev/index.php?mod=tablesorter_ajax&page=sale&col=1&order=DESC&view` it wont work

Comment: same goes for `http://localhost:8080/dev/mod/tablesorter_ajax.php&page=sale&col=1&order=‌​DESC&view`

Comment: I can't really get much from that screenshot - does it not display any errors anywhere? How about the console? .... Also, this is what I normally use for the same action, try it instead (note that it POST's the variables): `$.post(
    location, 
    data,
    function(data, textStatus, XHR)
    {
    }
  );`

Answer (score 0):

This is a cross domain request. Because you are using **Localhost**. So u can add following code into your php file. Then you send request using ajax.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
}
```

Its work's good

Comment: well, if he's running the page from localhost, it wouldn't be cross-domain now, would it?